# error cannot read property 'tracks' of null (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create track to album but i'm stuck at one error

This is my route code

```
// Adding track to album
router.get('/:album_id/track/new', function(req, res){
    Album.findById(req.params.album_id, function(err, falbum){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('tracks/add', {albums: falbum});
        }
    });
});

// Post routes
router.post('/:album_id/track',upload.single('songs'), function(req, res){
    Album.findById(req.params.album_id, function(err, album){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(req.file){
                console.log('Uploading Song ....');
                var songs = req.file.filename;
            } else {
                console.log('No Song Uploaded...');
            }
            var songname = req.body.songname;
            var songs = songs;
            var newSong = {songname: songname, songs:songs};

            Track.create(newSong, function(err, track){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    track.albumId.id = req.params.album_id;
                    track.save();
                    album.tracks.push(track);
                    album.save();
                    console.log('New Track is created');
                    res.redirect('/albums/' + album._id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/:album_id',function(req, res){
    Album.findById(req.params.album_id).populate('tracks').exec(function(err, album){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('albums/show', {albums: album})
        }
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

And i get this following error

```
v4\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tracks' of null
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\routes\albums.js:53:11
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3324:16)
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1870:14
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:726:13
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:17
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37
    at model.callbackWrapper (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1843:11)
    at next_ (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\hooks-fixed\hooks.js:89:34)
    at fnWrapper (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\hooks-fixed\hooks.js:186:8)
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3324:16
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:228:5
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:135:7
    at C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:504:5
```

what should i do? what about this error?
i tried to change tracks to track but i still got error 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe i wrong but i think your query Album.findById(req.params.album_id) doesnt return results thats why populate throws error. Try to check is query actually find data. Hope this helps.

Comment: The error means one thing, the `Album.findById()` query did not find any matching document with that `album_id` hence the result variable `album` in the callback is undefined and thus throws an error on `album.tracks.push(track);`. You need to check if the result is a document first.

Comment: Can you show your schema? also can you tell which line is it referring to : `C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\pidal-v4\routes\albums.js:53:11`

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify `Album.findById` returns an `album`?

It seems your database query is not matching any documents and therefore `album` is undefined so you cannot access the tracks property on the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing mistake in `pushing tracks` in `albums` document after `track` is successfully created.

You should push `track._id` instead of `track`.(As i can see you are trying to pupulate the tracks, thus you must have used `ObjectId` and `reference` in your `schema`).

When you are pushing whole `track` `document`, `album` might not be successfully saved. since there is no callback attached with it (`album.save()`), it is not showing you the actual `error`. Thus no `album` document is created, and it is giving `null` when you are using `album.findById`

This is why it is showing you this error while using `populate('tracks')` **:**  `cannot read property tracks of null.`

```
Track.create(newSong, function(err, track){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                track.albumId.id = req.params.album_id;
                track.save();
                album.tracks.push(track._id);//Here _id should be pushed.
                album.save();
                console.log('New Track is created');
                res.redirect('/albums/' + album._id);
            }
        });
```